# How to remove a single mapbox android annotation?

Tags: kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

I only started learning mapbox maps and I'm trying to remove a mapbox annotation every time I create another annotation.

My code:

```
bitmapFromDrawableRes(
            this@PagePlanRouteMap,
            R.drawable.red_marker

        )?.let {

            val annotationApi = mapView?.annotations
            val pointAnnotationManager = annotationApi?.createPointAnnotationManager(mapView!!)


            val pointAnnotationOptions: PointAnnotationOptions = PointAnnotationOptions()

                .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(lng, lat))
                .withIconImage(it)

            pointAnnotationManager?.create(pointAnnotationOptions)
        }
```

Can you help me implement the deleting of annotation using --

pointAnnotationManager?.deleteAll()

or is there another better way for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `delete()` method from your `pointAnnotationManager`.
It has 2 different parameters you can pass through: either a `PointAnnotation` object or a list of `PointAnnotation`.

For example:

```
val pointAnnotation = pointAnnotationManager?.create(pointAnnotationOptions)
pointAnnotationManager?.delete(pointAnnotation)
```

OR

```
pointAnnotationManager?.delete(listOf(pointAnnotation))
```

Comment: Also worth commenting, since I found it out the hard way my self. Every annotation has it's own point annotation manager. I store all my point annotation managers locally, if I need to remove multiple annotations I just loop through my list of point annotation managers and use the delete function inside the foreach loop.

Comment: There should only be one point annotation manager and you are most likely creating new instances.

Comment: That's what you would think @Codeversed but I haven't found a way yet to set multiple annotations on the map with one pointAnnotationManager. Seems like you have to use a single one for each marker on the map. Or at least I couldn't find any other way. (btw I'm still a junior so I might be making it overcomplicated but Mapbox doesn't really properly write docs anymore compared to 4 years ago when they had great docs)

Comment: use: remember { mapView.annotations.createPointAnnotationManager() }

Comment: That would work if your using Compose, but what if your not? Or is remember also something you can use outside Compose for Android?

Comment: If you are not using Compose, it should be more obvious if you are creating more than one instance but unless I would see your code I couldn't tell you how to fix it. I would suggest revisiting that code because you should only have one manager instance for each type of annotation manager.

Answer (score 1):

pointAnnotationManager?.deleteAll() is not working for me if you want to delete all points you can use this
binding.mapView.annotations.cleanup()